# Routing without specifying exact link in Angular

Tags: angular

How could I create a path to a component without specifying the exact link? For example, down below I want to create a path for such a link `/list/:id/(any string)`

```
{
    path: 'list/:id/',
    component: ListDetailComponent
  }
```

So `/list/5/Angular-Components` and `/list/43/programming-languages` will direct to the same component.

Answer (score 2):

Angular supports *wild-card* routes; so just put a ** after it:

```
path: 'list/:id/**',
```

Note that Angular evaluates from top to bottom; so if you had

```
path: 'list/:id/programming-languages'
```

*beneath* that entry in the routing configuration it would be totally unreachable. Wildcard routes should be placed at the bottom of the config.

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-directives

Comment: `{
    path: 'list/:id/**',
    component: ListDetailComponent
  },
  {//must be the last one
    path: "**",
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }`

Comment: @AZSH I've only done the "global" version; but if anything would work for children I'd think that would

Comment: It always direct me to PageNotFound Component. here is the linke I have `http://localhost:4200/list/2/Angular` this link lead me to the PageNotFound component